# How to point webpack externals to a property of a default export?

Tags: webpack

Another team at my company has a react app that is bundled by webpack as an AMD module, which exports a single object with named properties. It looks something like:

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
const App = require('./src/App.js');

module.exports = {
  React: React,
  ReactDOM: ReactDOM,
  App: App,
};
```

My team is making another react application that will run on the same page and we would like to reuse React and ReactDOM from the existing package. How can I define `externals` in my webpack config to resolve react and reactdom to those exported from the other package?

Essentially I need to rewrite:

```
const React = require('react');
```

to

```
const React = require('OtherTeamsPackage').React;
```